# react-native-router-flux throws Actions is not defined

Tags: undefined, action, react-native-router-flux

Trying to start with a super simple react-native-router-flux example using 4.0.0-beta.28.  I receive the dreaded red screen that the Action is undefined.  I am guessing I have something semantically incorrect?

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Scene,Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import LoginScreen from '../shoppinglist/screens/login'
import LandingScreen from '../shoppinglist/screens/landing'

import {
    Platform,
    AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

const MyApp = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key={"root"}>
                <Scene key="login" component={LoginScreen} title="Login">
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="home" component={LandingScreen} title="Home" initial></Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('shoppinglist', () => MyApp)
```

Code that triggers Action:

```
 <Button onPress={() => Actions.home()} title={'Navigate to Login'} />
```

[Simulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43keV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing Actions from your import directive:

```
import { Actions, Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```